# Error with expo "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on expo using react native and am getting the following error .I am not sure what's causing it and what the error means exactly.

I did run the files separately but they were working fine.
Error with expo "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

[image]

Code for App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Header from './components/Header.js';
import Body2 from './components/Body2.js';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import DisplayAnImage from '/components/mapimage.js';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header />
      <DisplayAnImage />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Code for Header.js

```
import { Text,Button,SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

function Header()
{
  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.fixToText}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>TaskStatus : Scheduled</Text>
       <Button
          title="History" style={styles.buton}
          /*onPress={History}*//>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    margin: 5,
    marginTop:30,
  },
  text: {
    marginTop:10,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  fixToText: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  buton:
  {
    width:20,
    height:20,
    margin:20,
  }
});

export default Header;
```

Code for DisplayImage

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  map: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
});

const DisplayAnImage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.map}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://i0.wp.com/cssscript.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Simple-Location-Picker.png?fit=561%2C421&ssl=1',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default DisplayAnImage;
```

Comment: You need to include the rest of your code

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `Home`, `Body2`, and `DisplayAnImage` component code? If I had to guess, the issue looks like it's in `'/components/mapimage.js'` but let's be thorough.

Comment: Upload all of your components

Comment: I did run the rest separately and its working fine. I thought the error was in this file only

Comment: Then you maybe exporting the wrong things as default exports.

Comment: i have uploaded all the codes

Comment: Try commenting out all but the `View`, then try adding the `Header`, then `DisplayAnImage`... you're looking for which component breaks the app. Dig into *that* component.

Comment: One problem is with your button in header.js. You cannot apply styles on a button from react-native

Comment: its not making any difference

Comment: Still getting the error

Comment: Tried this code in snack. It works fine

Comment: i am still getting the error .It worked fine for me for the first time but on refreshing i got the error.

Comment: If you are doing this on snack.expo.io then share it's link

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. It got resolved on refreshing the expo ;)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. It got resolved on refreshing the expo ;)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. It got resolved on refreshing the expo ;)